# How to check hashed password stored in PSQL DB

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, bcrypt

I want to verify the password by hashing it and then checking the hash on the PSQL DB

I am trying to compare the hashes - but I am getting an error of `Invalid Salt.`

Here is my code:

```
@app.route("/hello", methods=["POST", "GET"])
 def hello():
 email = request.form.get("email")
 password = request.form.get("password")
 password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
 db.execute("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, 
 :password)",{"email": email, "password": password})
 db.commit()
```

AND

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def check():
    email = request.form.get("login_email")
    check_email_in_db = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = :email", {"email": email}).fetchall()
    if check_email_in_db[0][0] == 1 :
        email = request.form.get("login_email")
        password = request.form.get("login_password")
        retrive_password_from_db = db.execute("SELECT password FROM 
        users WHERE email = :email", {"email": email}).fetchall()
        retrive_password_from_db = retrive_password_from_db[0][0]
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(password, retrive_password_from_db):
            return("this works")
        else:
            return("something is wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  All I had to do was, specify the rounds while hashing:

```
password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password, 10).decode('utf-8')
```